# Read scons build variables from a external.py file

Tags: scons

I want to define the scons build variables in external.py file like

### external.py

```
mode=debug
toolchain=x86
```

This I want to read back these variables in the SConstruct file which is there in the same directory. Depending on the variable values I want to do some operations!

```
vars = Variables('external.py')
vars.Add('mode', 'Set the mode for debug or release', 'debug')
if ${RELEASE}=="debug"
   #Do these!
elif ${RELEASE}=="release"
   #Do that!
```

Answer (score 1):

If `external.py` contains valid Python code then you can simply import it using the `import` keyword. You can then use the `dir` function to iterate over the names defined in the `external` module and add them to the SCons variables. You might also want to take a look at the `getattr` function.

Answer (score 1):

The thing you are missing is Scons Environment with your variables.

```py
vars = Variables('external.py')
vars.Add('mode', 'Set the mode for debug or release', 'debug')

env = Environment(variables = vars)

if env['mode'] == 'debug':
    # do action1
elif env['mode'] == 'release':
    # do action2
else:
    # do action3
```

You can read more about using Scons [here](http://scons.org/doc/HTML/scons-user/book1.html), and about your question [here](http://scons.org/doc/HTML/scons-user/x2445.html#AEN2557)

Answer (score 1):

Soumyajit answer is great but I would add that if you want to be able to override values from your file with the command line and restrain the allowed values for your variables you can do as follow:

```py
# Build variables are loaded in this order:
# Command Line (ARGUMENTS) >> Config File (external.py) >> Default Value
vars = Variables(files='external.py', args=ARGUMENTS)
vars.Add(EnumVariable('mode', 'Build mode.', 'debug', allowed_values=('debug', 'release')))

env = Environment(variables = vars)

if env['mode'] == 'debug':
    env.Append(CCFLAGS = [ '-g' ])
    # whatever...
else:
    env.Append(CCFLAGS = '-O2')
    # whatever...
```

You can invoke you build script like this `scons` but also override specific variables without editing your config file by doing `scons mode=release`

If you specify a bad value for your variable you will get an error from Scons like:

```sh
$> scons mode=foo
scons: Reading SConscript files ...
scons: *** Invalid value for option mode: foo.  Valid values are: ('debug', 'release')
```