# Import scons variables from file

Tags: build, environment-variables, scons

Does `scons` support including variables from an external file?

In short, I have a bunch of settings, variables, etc; that I want to make available to a bunch of Makefiles in a large project of mine. It's easy enough for the root-level makefile to simply source/include the file.

However, some sub-projects use `scons`, and [the only documentation I found on the topic notes](http://scons.org/doc/1.2.0/HTML/scons-user/x3186.html) that a top-level sconscript needs to create an pass down the variables to sub-projects.

My goal is to have a simple file full of variables (mainly paths to compilers), and tell `scons` to just import the variable key/value pairs. [The one SO post I've found on this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20122810/read-scons-build-variables-from-a-external-py-file) notes that the file must be [python](/questions/tagged/python) code, rather than a Makefile, so I'd potentially need to write a script to convert the Makefile to python code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you check the scons manpage  ( http://scons.org/doc/production/HTML/scons-man.html search for "variables(" )

You'll see Variables() can take a file (python).  Though its won't likely solve your question.  It's possible to have that file be a format which is both valid python and valid make, highly dependent on the contents of course.

Excluding that, it should be fairly simple to parse a simple makefile assuming it's contents are something like:

```
xyz = some values
abc := some other values
```

If it contains

```
xyz = some values
abc := $(xyz) and more
```

It will get far more complicated.